# Where to save configuration data for web application?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing small application.
It is small CMS like application. Admin of this site should have option to change settings in application. Like text in header, message of the day.

Where should I store those values? Table in database? Some kind of file? I want admin to be able to change those values from website without manually editing files on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the small table in DB with WebSiteSettings would be the best solution as for me.

**EDITED**

WebSiteSettings table example:

```
PK Id               [int]              not null
   StrTmplVal_1     [nvarchar(128)]    null
   StrTmplVal_2     [nvarchar(256)]    null
   StrTmplVal_3     [nvarchar(512)]    null
   BoolTmplVal_1    [bit]              null
   BoolTmplVal_2    [bit]              null
   BoolTmplVal_3    [bit]              null
   IntTmplVal_1     [int]              null
   IntTmplVal_2     [int]              null
   IntTmplVal_3     [int]              null
```

WebSiteSettings model example for an individual website:

```
   SettingsId            -> Id               
   SiteName              -> StrTmplVal_1     
   PageHeader            -> StrTmplVal_2     
   WelcomeText           -> StrTmplVal_3     
   IsDemoVersion         -> BoolTmplVal_1     
   IsTilesShowed         -> BoolTmplVal_2    
   MaxRowCountOnPage     -> IntTmplVal_1     
   WelcomeAnimationDelay -> IntTmplVal_2
```

Comment: But how should it look? Table with "key" "value" columns?
What about diference in value length type?

How is it solved in "big" applications?

Comment: You can create table with several columns with string, int and bool types and map them on different models for different sites. I now that for site headers (and other things) you don't need huge number of templates and they is no very large (string vars less than 512 characters as usual).

Comment: That is good idea with this "many columns". I get it. But if you want to have answer accepted you should edit it little bit more and give example for other people that may come here in future. Thanks again for idea.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Ok, I'll add little table model in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a table following this structure would be a start:

**Table Settings**
`ID(int, primary key), Name(varchar)`

**Table SettingValues** `ID(int, primary key), SettingID(int foreign key), Value(blob)`

Please note that I use BLOB (Binary Large Object) type for the actual value of the setting. Therefore, you could save the settings just by serializing them.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Nice, but I don't get why not have single table with Name and Value (blob)? I'm new to SQL and I'm intrested in learnign those small tricks.

Comment: Because for some settings you could have many values... In case you don't need a "one-to-many" relation, you could put it all in one table...